# Dynamically create Backend section in HAProxy configuration

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I have a use case where i need to use HAProxy as a proxy rather than a loadbalancer. So in my case i need many backend sections that need to be updated in the config when proxy is started.

But is there a way , where i can create new backend section dynamically ?

```
global

log stdout format raw daemon
stats socket ipv4@127.0.0.1:9999 level admin
stats socket /var/run/hapee-lb.sock mode 666 level admin
stats timeout 2m

defaults

log global
timeout client 50s
timeout client-fin 50s
timeout connect 5s
timeout server 10s
timeout tunnel 50s

frontend tcp-0_0_0_0-443

bind 135.27.110.163:443
mode tcp
tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }    
use_backend %[req.ssl_sni,regsub(.com,.com443,g),lower,map_dom(/usr/local/etc/sample.map,bk_default)]
default_backend example_com_be

frontend tcp-0_0_0_0-5061

bind 135.27.110.163:5061
mode tcp
tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
use_backend %[req.ssl_sni,regsub(.com,.com5061,g),lower,map_dom(/usr/local/etc/sample.map,bk_default)]   
default_backend absanity_5061

backend example_com_be

mode tcp
server name1 x.x.x.x:443

backend absanity_5061

mode tcp
server name1 y.y.y.y:5061
```

AM using Runtime API using Socat for updating maps. But assume i was to insert a new backend section with new server details in config .. how can we achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can create new backends at runtime with the socket API.  This article gives a good overview of what you can modify at runtime: https://www.haproxy.com/blog/dynamic-configuration-haproxy-runtime-api/.

However, you can add new backends without using the socket API by creating a new config with the new backends and reloading HAProxy.  This article gives a good overview of how to reload HAProxy without losing connections:
https://www.haproxy.com/blog/truly-seamless-reloads-with-haproxy-no-more-hacks/

Comment: i have tried above links , but doesn't fit my requirement. I can use hitless reload after updating config. it works but lot of disadvantages associated with that. Worker threads keep on accumulating for each reload and ends up with may worker thread running at a time. so cant really use HAproxy for this thing. Nways i was able to achieve it from NGINIX proxy so am fine . Thanks for your response.

Comment: It's a bit late, but HAProxy just released their dataplane API which allows you to dynamically add and remove servers. https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-2-0-and-beyond/#data-plane-api

Comment: its never too late :) Helped me :)